# Find all the generated values of an array of numbers in a given range

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, generator, sequence

Imagine this scenario:

**Input**
array of numbers and a boundary range for the output:
 `numbers = [20, 50]`
`range = [0, 200]`

**Output**
all possible combination of the sums of the elements of the input array restricted to the boundary range:
`output = [20, 40, 50, 70, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]`

So my question isHow can I achieve this?

Comment: if range is from 0 - 200 why 0, 10 , 30 ,60 are left out? Also show your code what you tried.

Comment: You can do it the *C-way*, *Java-way* or whatever, all that changes is the syntax.

Comment: @maraca you're right, I've edited the question for a general solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array of `Int(s)` and a closed range

```
let numbers = [20, 50]
let range: ClosedRange = 0...200
```

The following function returns a `Set` of every possible integer which satisfy the following conditions:

1. it is within the range
2. can be expressed as sum of some values (repeated if needed) in `numbers`

### Code

```
func combs(range:ClosedRange<Int>, numers: [Int], value: Int = 0) -> Set<Int> {

    guard value <= range.upperBound else { return [] }

    return numbers.reduce(Set<Int>()) { results, num -> Set<Int> in
        var results = results
        let newValue = value + num
        if range ~= value {
            results.insert(value)
        }
        return results.union(combs(range: range, numers: numbers, value: newValue))
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let nums = Array(combs(range: range, numers: numbers)).sorted()
```

> [0, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]

Comment: This solution works,  but it is not at all efficient. For example, when I try with a range of [0, 500]  the function and the reduce closure are called 70078 and  140156 times respectively.

Comment: @Taglia: yes this is backtracking. A safe but expensive approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible method which gives the numbers in increasing order.
It uses two arrays ("queues") to keep track of values which still have to
be added to the output sequence. (This is essentially the same method as
the "Dynamic Programming Method" in ["Ugly Numbers"](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/) to generate the so-called Hamming numbers.)

```
let x = 20
let y = 50
let limit = 200

var xq: [Int] = []
var yq: [Int] = []
var current = 0

while current <= limit {
    print(current, terminator: ", ")

    xq.append(current + x)
    yq.append(current + y)

    current = min(xq[0], yq[0])
    if xq[0] == current { xq.remove(at: 0) }
    if yq[0] == current { yq.remove(at: 0) }
}
print()
```

Output:

```
0, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200,
```

Comment: Although @appzYourLife answer is correct, I found this one more suited for my intention: is efficient for a small number of elements in input (2 in my case). I've tested it with 3 elements in input and works perfectly.